# Is there a python class in Azure SDK to reserve Public IP address of an instance?

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am trying to reserve public IP address of an Azure VM before switching it off or deallocating it, but I am not able to find any python class in Azure SDK for this. When I switch off my VM in UI it asks if I want to reserve the public IP address. I want the class with the same functionality. How can I solve this?

I tried saving the public IP to variable and passing it to NIC after my VM turns off, but it turns out it doesn't accept the IP which I give.

```
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials=setup['values'], subscription_id=test_bed.subscription_id)

parapip = network_client.models().PublicIPAddress(location='West US', public_ip_allocation_method='Static', ip_address='104.42.218.83')

network_client.public_ip_addresses.create_or_update(resource_group_name=setup['resource_group_name'], public_ip_address_name='mgmt2-pip-jp07zf', parameters=parapip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, If you have a **Dynamic** assignment public IP address associated with that Azure VM, the UI asks if you want to reserve the public IP address when you stop the VM in the Azure portal. If you have a **Static** assignment public IP address before you stop the VM, then the UI will not ask if you want to reserve the public IP address.

For this, If you already have a static public IP, then the IP address will not be lost if you stop the VM. You may change your code to set the IP address dynamic. For example, to create a public IP address for the virtual machine, add this function after the variables in the `.py` file:

`def create_public_ip_address(network_client):
    public_ip_addess_params = {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'public_ip_allocation_method': 'Dynamic'
    }
    creation_result = network_client.public_ip_addresses.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        'myIPAddress',
        public_ip_addess_params
    )
    return creation_result.result()`

If you want to deallocate the virtual machine, you could use this code,

```
def stop_vm(compute_client):
    compute_client.virtual_machines.deallocate(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME)
```

More details from [Create and manage Windows VMs in Azure using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python).

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if there is a class which reserves the IP address just like UI does. Like - network_client.public_ip_addresses.reserve() - something like this?

Comment: I don't think there is such a class. The reserve() action in UI actually is to change the public IP assignment static.